# Issue with Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client nuget package

Tags: visual-studio-2012, json.net, signalr, nuget, signalr.client

Whenever i do a clean build of my solution i get the following build error from any projects that have the Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client nuget package installed:

'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client' already has a dependency defined for 'Newtonsoft.Json'

If I go to package manager and click on Restor packages it starts building fine

Any ideas whats going on here?

Answer (score 5):

I was having this issue recently and realised that the NuGet Package Manager extension was not up-to-date. Updating the extension to the latest version (2.8.50313.31 for me) solved this problem.

Comment: i just hate it when i work on other machines and forget the stupid stuff, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you start visual studio by calling devenv.exe /log and then share the activitylog.xml from %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Version\ActivityLog.xml?

You can gather the repro steps and file an issue on https://nuget.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create, if it's a NuGet issue.